# Disable a row based on condition from database in Liferay Search Container

Tags: liferay, liferay-6, disabled-input, javascript

I have to disable a row that I retrieve from the database using Liferay search container. I have certain conditions stored in the database.

What I wish to achieve is this:

1. I am displaying a list of students whose attendance need to be marked.
2. Sometimes the students may take a leave in advance in which case the attendance is pre-marked in the database.
3. So when the form for marking attendance is displayed, I want to disable marking attendance by disabling the row containing the data of student whose attendance is already marked.

What I want to do is, if the attendance is pre-marked, show the row on the form with pre-marked attendance and do not allow the user to mark attendance for that student i.e. disable the row.

How can I achieve this?

EDITED:
The code snippet

```
    Mark Attendance for Today:   
    <%=new java.util.Date()%>

    <portlet:actionURL name="updateAtt" var="updateAttURL" />

        <aui:form name="updateAtt" action="<%=updateAttURL.toString() %>" method="post" >

            Choose Date to mark Attendance:
            <liferay-ui:input-date formName="attendanceDate" yearRangeStart="<%=year %>" yearRangeEnd="<%=year %>"
                    yearValue="<%=year %>" monthValue="<%=month %>" dayValue="<%=day %>" 
                    dayParam="datt" monthParam="matt" yearParam="yatt" />

            <portlet:renderURL  var="viewstudentDataURL"/>

            <liferay-ui:search-container delta="20" emptyResultsMessage="No Results Found">

                <liferay-ui:search-container-results total="<%= studentAttendanceDetails .size() %>"
                        results="<%= ListUtil.subList(studentAttendanceDetails , searchContainer.getStart(), searchContainer.getEnd()) %>" />
                <liferay-ui:search-container-row modelVar="search"
                    className="com.corpserver.mis.portal.model.Student">   

                    <%
                    String LImageId = String.valueOf(search.getFileEntryId());
                    long ImageId = Long.valueOf(LImageId);
                    DLFileEntry image = DLFileEntryLocalServiceUtil .getFileEntry(ImageId ); 
                    String imageURL = "/documents/" + image.getGroupId() + "/" + image.getFolderId() + "/" + image.getTitle()+"/"+image.getUuid();
                    %>

                    <liferay-ui:search-container-column-text name="student Photo" href = "">
                        <img src="<%=imageURL%>" height="50" width="50"/> 
                    </liferay-ui:search-container-column-text>
                    <!-- Code to display student Image -->

                    <%
                    String eol = System.getProperty("line.separator");
                    %>

                    <liferay-ui:search-container-column-text name='student Name' value='<%=String.valueOf(search.getstudentFname()) +  String.valueOf(search.getstudentLname()) + "<br>" + String.valueOf(search.getstudentTitle()) %>'  href="" >

                    </liferay-ui:search-container-column-text>

                    <liferay-ui:search-container-column-text name="Attendance Status">                       
                        <label>Present</label><input type = "radio" name ='updateattendance<%=String.valueOf(search.getstudentId())%>' value = "Present" />
                        <label>Absent</label><input type = "radio" name= 'updateattendance<%=String.valueOf(search.getstudentId())%>' value = "Absent"/>
                    </liferay-ui:search-container-column-text>

                </liferay-ui:search-container-row>

                <liferay-ui:search-iterator searchContainer="<%=searchContainer %>" paginate="<%=true %>" />
            </liferay-ui:search-container>

            <input type = "submit" value = "Update"/>
        </aui:form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi, would you be ok with disabling the input control that marks the attendance ? If yes, give us the jsp code for the search container row

Comment: @yannicuLar:
I have updated the ques with the code snippet that m using..

Comment: @SeeyaK ___Unrelated to the question:___ I saw in your code `</body>` and `</html>` tags. In your portlet's jsp these html tags should not be present since portlets are meant to generate only fragments and these tags are added by the portal automatically. In some browsers you may get weird behaviour when you use javascript because there would be more than one `</body>` and `</html>` tags which is not a well-formed html page. So in short we should not include `<html>`,`<body>`, `<head>`, `<title>` etc tags in portlet's jsp. Thanks

Comment: @Prakash K : Thanks for that.. Will make a note of this and use ur suggestion.

Comment: obviously you will have to inject some java code in the 'Attendance Status' column, and manipulate the <input> fields, by e.g using the disabled attribute. The question is how can you get the 'marked attendance' value (is it an attribute of the 'search' instance of the 'com.corpserver.mis.portal.model.Student' Class ??)

Comment: by the way, It would be nice to check the correct input (Present/Absent) when populating the search container, so you'll need the Java code injection anyway

Comment: @yannicuLar:
To answer your ques whether the "marked attendance" is an attribute..The answer is No. There will be a form to apply for leave. If the leave is granted, then the attendance table is updated and the student is marked absent for the leave duration. ex. if A's on leave for next 5 days, he is marked absent for next 5 days in advance. When marking attendance everyday, for the next 5 days, A will be shown as already marked absent and his attendance cannot be altered. I hope this answered your query.

Answer (score 1):

You can use conditional statements to just show the label instead of the input control or disabled the input control, as follows:

```
<%
String LImageId = String.valueOf(search.getFileEntryId());
long ImageId = Long.valueOf(LImageId);
DLFileEntry image = DLFileEntryLocalServiceUtil .getFileEntry(ImageId ); 
String imageURL = "/documents/" + image.getGroupId() + "/" + image.getFolderId() + "/" + image.getTitle()+"/"+image.getUuid();

// you can define a flag for the pre-marked attendance
boolean preMarkFlag = isStudentPreMarked(); // have value true (student is premarked) or false (if the student is not pre-maked)    
%>

<liferay-ui:search-container-column-text name="Attendance Status">
    <label>Present</label>
    <input type = "radio"
            name ='updateattendance<%=String.valueOf(search.getstudentId())%>'
            value = "Present"
            <%= preMarkFlag ? "disabled" : "" %> />

    <label>Absent</label>
    <input type = "radio"
            name ='updateattendance<%=String.valueOf(search.getstudentId())%>'
            value = "Absent"
            <%= preMarkFlag ? "disabled" : "" %> />
</liferay-ui:search-container-column-text>
```

Or another way is to just show a label and not show the input radio-button at all

```
<liferay-ui:search-container-column-text name="Attendance Status">
    <%
    // I am assuming if preMarkFlag is true then the student is absent
    // as mentioned in your question
    if (preMarkFlag) {
    %>

    <label>Absent</label>

    <%
    } else {
    %>

    <label>Present</label>
    <input type = "radio"
            name ='updateattendance<%=String.valueOf(search.getstudentId())%>'
            value = "Present"
            <%= preMarkFlag ? "disabled" : "" %> />

    <label>Absent</label>
    <input type = "radio"
            name ='updateattendance<%=String.valueOf(search.getstudentId())%>'
            value = "Absent"
            <%= preMarkFlag ? "disabled" : "" %> />

    <%
    }
    %>
</liferay-ui:search-container-column-text>
```

Comment: Should I use custom-query to check if the attendance of students are pre-marked?

Comment: @SeeyaK I assumed you already knew that how the particular student is pre-marked, since you have not given any details in the question as to how you are storing the attendance and how are storing pre-marked attendance. So without this information it would be difficult to suggest. But I think you would definitely need a method to check that and the internal implementation can be a custom-query if it is not straight forward or cannot be done through dynamicQuery.

Comment: I agree with Prakash, you should have a method in your Controller Class that will take as argument a com.corpserver.mis.portal.model.Student, and return a boolean or int. In your jsp, inside the column code, Call this function (give the 'search' variable, as your modelVar attr declares) and use the result to hide or disable the radio/checkbox controls. You question was how to disable these controls, and I think that Prakash's answer covers that

Comment: @Prakash K:
There will be a form to apply for leave. If the leave is granted, then the attendance table is updated and the student is marked absent for the leave duration. ex. if A's on leave for next 5 days, he is marked absent for next 5 days in advance. When marking attendance everyday, for the next 5 days, A will be shown as already marked absent and his attendance cannot be altered. I hope this answered your query.